# Best Way to Query over time window in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with records of sales from `2021-01-01 to 2021-09-27`, like this:

```
Order_Date     Order_number
2021-09-27        8989
.
.
.
2021-01-01        56565
```

I want to query the count of orders in the last `1day, 2days, 5 days, 30days` etc...

I know how to use the `where date(Order_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '1' day`

but can I query over these time intervals in the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FILTER.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE date(Order_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '1' day)) as day1,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE date(Order_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '2' day)) as day2,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE date(Order_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '5' day)) as day5
FROM whatever
```